# c# not returning byte array asmx web service

Tags: c#, web-services, iis, arrays, asmx

I have a C# Web Service that works well in Visual Studio Debug but does not return the bytearray part of my custom calls in IIS

**Response from Web Service in IIS**

```
<Surname>Midlton</Surname><Firstname>Katrin</Firstname><Middlename/><Gender>Female</Gender><MaritalStatus>Separated</MaritalStatus><DateOfBirth>7/1/1965 12:00:00 AM</DateOfBirth><Religion/><PermanentAddress>Oktabrjskaya</PermanentAddress><City>AKURE</City><State>IMO</State><Country>NG</Country><Nationality/><Occupation>ADVERTISING PRACTITIONER</Occupation><IDType/><IDNumber/><MobileNumber>98765432</MobileNumber><EmailAddress>sunstroke@mail.ttt</EmailAddress><IssueDebitCard>true</IssueDebitCard><PreferredName>1234567899876543211</PreferredName><EnableUDirect>0</EnableUDirect><UDirectUsername>1234567897</UDirectUsername><EnableEmailAlert>1</EnableEmailAlert><EnableEstatement>1</EnableEstatement><Title>Mrs.</Title><SolID>0280</SolID><CardType>Visa Dual Currency</CardType><EnableSMSAlert>1</EnableSMSAlert><RecordID>51008</RecordID><AccountTypeName>FREEDOM  SAVINGS  ACCOUNT  (BASIC)</AccountTypeName><AccountTypeID>3</AccountTypeID>
```

Response Debugging in VS

```
<Surname>Midlton</Surname><Firstname>Katrin</Firstname><Middlename/><Gender>Female</Gender><MaritalStatus>Separated</MaritalStatus><DateOfBirth>7/1/1965 12:00:00 AM</DateOfBirth><Religion/><PermanentAddress>Oktabrjskaya</PermanentAddress><City>AKURE</City><State>IMO</State><Country>NG</Country><Nationality/><Occupation>ADVERTISING PRACTITIONER</Occupation><IDType/><IDNumber/><MobileNumber>98765432</MobileNumber><EmailAddress>sunstroke@mail.ttt</EmailAddress><IssueDebitCard>true</IssueDebitCard><PreferredName>1234567899876543211</PreferredName><EnableUDirect>0</EnableUDirect><UDirectUsername>1234567897</UDirectUsername><EnableEmailAlert>1</EnableEmailAlert><EnableEstatement>1</EnableEstatement><Title>Mrs.</Title><SolID>0280</SolID><CardType>Visa Dual Currency</CardType><EnableSMSAlert>1</EnableSMSAlert><RecordID>51008</RecordID><AccountTypeName>FREEDOM  SAVINGS  ACCOUNT  (BASIC)</AccountTypeName><AccountTypeID>3</AccountTypeID><UploadFile>dfdfEWESD345SDSDssDfdsf</UploadFile>
```

I would really like to know why the bytearray part of the response is stripped out in IIS.

```
 AOData accountOpeningData = new AOData();         


                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText);
                command.Connection = connection;



                reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    recordID = reader["RecordID"].ToString();
                    accountOpeningData.RecordID = recordID;
                    accountOpeningData.AccountTypeID = reader["AccountTypeID"].ToString();
                    accountOpeningData.AccountTypeName = reader["AccountTypeName"].ToString();
                    accountOpeningData.Surname = reader["LastName"].ToString();
                    accountOpeningData.Firstname = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
                    accountOpeningData.EmailAddress = reader["Email"].ToString();
                    accountOpeningData.Middlename = reader["MiddleName"].ToString();
                    accountOpeningData.Gender = reader["Gender"].ToString();
                    accountOpeningData.MaritalStatus = reader["MaritalStatus"].ToString();


                    accountOpeningData.DateOfBirth = reader["DOB"].ToString();
                    accountOpeningData.Religion = String.Empty; //reader["Religion"].ToString();
                    accountOpeningData.PermanentAddress = reader["Address"].ToString();
                    accountOpeningData.City = reader["City"].ToString();
                    accountOpeningData.State = reader["State"].ToString();
                    accountOpeningData.Country = reader["Country"].ToString();
                    accountOpeningData.Nationality = String.Empty; //reader["Nationality"].ToString();
                    accountOpeningData.Occupation = reader["Occupation"].ToString();
                    accountOpeningData.IDType = String.Empty; //reader["IdentificationForm"].ToString();
                    accountOpeningData.IDNumber = String.Empty; //reader["INumber"].ToString();
                    accountOpeningData.MobileNumber = reader["Tel1"].ToString();
                    accountOpeningData.IssueDebitCard = true; //Convert.ToBoolean(reader["SDebitcard"].ToString());
                    accountOpeningData.CardType = reader["CardType"].ToString();
                    accountOpeningData.PreferredName = reader["PreferedName"].ToString();
                    accountOpeningData.Title = reader["Title"].ToString();
                    accountOpeningData.SolID = reader["NewCode"].ToString();
                    accountOpeningData.EnableUDirect = reader["Udirect"].ToString();
                    accountOpeningData.UDirectUsername = reader["Uname"].ToString();
                    accountOpeningData.EnableEmailAlert = reader["EmailAlert"].ToString();
                    accountOpeningData.EnableSMSAlert = reader["SmsAlert"].ToString();
                    accountOpeningData.EnableEstatement = reader["eStatement"].ToString();

                    string code = reader["Code"].ToString();

                    accountOpeningData.UploadFile = GetUploadedFiles(code);


                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Print error message
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (reader != null)
                    reader.Close();

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    connection.Close();
            }

            return accountOpeningData;
        }
```

Comment: did you add your byte array property to your type you are returning?

Comment: Add some code that you use to send the object

Comment: @Eminem Added the code that returns the object

Comment: test your code as following: "This is a test" // GetUploadedFiles(code);  This is to make sure that there isn't something wrong with your GetUploadedFiles(code) function.

Comment: also is accountOpeningData.UploadFile a string?

Comment: @Eminem that property is a bytearray, which the method GetUploadedFiles returns, as I said it works perfectly running from Visual Studio

Comment: Does your IIS have the same .NET framework configuration with your application?

Comment: @OrkunBekar my application runs on .Net 3.5 why the Application pool is running on .Net Version 2.0, could that be the issue?

Comment: I think so. Change IIS .net version and try again.

Comment: Done that still no luck, that property is not being returned

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem by implementing WSE 3.0. I set it up as instructed [here](http://digantakumar.com/2010/06/04/wse-3-in-visual-studio-2008-and-2010/)

and followed the instruction [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa528822.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to add it to my project